# How to locate the correct link directory files in my php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My problem the links is not correct it says "failed to load the resources" in the console.

Both code are not related. And the user.php is asking for connection from inside the dbc folder database.php and myScript.js wants to find user.php where is located inside the view folder.

Image of my current folder file tree:

http://s38.photobucket.com/user/eloginko/media/folder_zps2d422ae2.png.html

user.php

```
<?php
include_once('view/../dbc/database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($email) && !empty($pass)){
        $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * from user WHERE email=? AND password=?");
        $st->bindParam(1, $email);
        $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $st->execute();

        if($st->rowCount() == 1){
            echo "1";
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect Email or Password";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Please enter Email and Password";
    }  
?>
```

myScript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('div#show:empty').hide();
    $('#login').click(function(){

        var email = $('#lemail').val();
        var password = $('#lpassword').val();   

        $.ajax({
            data: {
             email : email, password : password
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: 'js/../view/user.php',
            success: function(data)
            {
               if (Number(data) == 1)
                    {           
                $(".show-page[data-page=progBar]").trigger("click");
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    }
                else
                    {
                  $('div#show:empty').show();
                  $('#show').html(data);
                    }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: give link to  ur site.

Answer (score 0):

Do following in myScript

```
  url: '../view/user.php',
```

Go back 1 folder from myscript and then find view folder ,and then find user.php file.

In user.php use same way

```
include_once('../dbc/database.php');
```

Comment: i've tried that but i doesnt work the console cant find the user after i click the login button but when i put all the page in the same folder i dont have problem...the linking of directory is the prob

Comment: try to see the image in my file tree i posted in my question

Answer (score 0):

using a url of "view/../dbc/database.php" is effectively the same as "dbc/database.php" as the .. only advises to drop back one directory.

for the php (since the PHP is in the view folder):

```
include_once('../dbc/database.php');
```

If the html/php file loading myScript.js is also in the "view" folder you can reference the path to the php file directly as the js uses the relative path of the file it is loaded into:

```
url: 'user.php',
```

Comment: try to see the image in my file tree i posted in my question